# Error while trying to use multiple classes with a constructor for a makefile

Tags: c++, class, makefile, constructor

I'm experimenting with makefiles, but it's not quite working out for me right now. The experiment is simple: a main.cpp that creates a robot with a function sayHello() that outpus "robot says hello" to the terminal. This is the code in my files.

robot.h:

```
 #include <stdio.h>
    class Robot(){

    public:
            Robot();
    public:
            void sayHello();

    };
```

robot.cpp

```
#include "robot.h"

Robot::Robot()
{
void Robot::sayHello(){
        printf("Robot says hello \r\n");
}

};
```

main.cpp

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "robot.h"


Robot robocop();
int main(void)
{
        printf("hello world \r\n");
        robocop.sayHello();
        return 0;
}
```

the error is as follows:

robot.h:2:13: error: expected unqualified-id before ‘)’ token
 class Robot(){
             ^
main.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
main.cpp:9:10: error: request for member ‘sayHello’ in ‘robocop’, which is of non-class type ‘Robot()’
  robocop.sayHello();

I've been trying on this for too long and could use some help. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with the makefile.

The class method definitions in `robot.cpp` are wrong. As written, the `sayHello()` method is, bizarrely, shoved inside the class's constructor. This is not correct. Each class method, including the constructor, has to be defined separately:

```
#include "robot.h"

Robot::Robot()
{
}

void Robot::sayHello()
{
        printf("Robot says hello \r\n");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've fixed it like this:

robot.h

```
#include <stdio.h>
class Robot{

public:
        Robot();
public:
        void sayHello();

};
```

robot.cpp

```
#include "robot.h"

Robot::Robot()
{}

void Robot::sayHello(){
        printf("Robot says hello \r\n");


}
```

main.cpp

```
#include "robot.h"


Robot robocop;
int main(void)
{

        robocop.sayHello();
        return 0;
}
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Main:

```
   int main()
{
Robot robocop;
printf("hello world \r\n");
robocop.sayHello();
system("pause>nul");
return 0;
}
```

P.S: Be careful when using system(). I used it in this example as it's the quickest, but I'd suggest using something else in the future; should work for this though.

Header:

```
class Robot {

public:
Robot();
void sayHello();
};
```

Robot.cpp:

```
Robot::Robot()
{
return;
}
void Robot::sayHello() {
    printf("Robot says hello \r\n");
    }
```

Pretty much as stated above, you had it written incorrectly. I'd suggest watching some tutorials on the basics of C++.